# decoding h.264 frame data in using AVAssetReader iOS

Tags: ios, video-streaming, ip-camera, avassetreader

I have some questions on AVAssetReader.
Currently I am reading view data sent from the IP Camera using the API provided by them.
From the API,

the following will return from the API for each frame

1.Buffer contain frame raw data

2.Frame type I or B frame

3.codec information : H.264

4.some other frame info from a FrameInfo object

Are the above information enough for decoding using AVAssetReader?

So far I see most examples is getting the video source from a URL or file, anyone can provide me sample codes that the decoding the raw data from frame buffer

much appreciated with your help